# Installing a Windows VM on Debian 7 by commandline

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtual

I want to install a virtual machine with windows 7 on my debian 7 server, but i don't know which software to use and how to process the windows setup without having to plug a screen into my server? any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this question would be more suited to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), but you should be able to do this utilizing VirtualBox.

Go ahead and install VirtualBox as per the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/VirtualBox) like so:

```
# apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') virtualbox
```

Then follow the guide here: http://xmodulo.com/how-to-create-and-start-virtualbox-vm-without-gui.html.

Remember that once you install Windows 7, you will need to enable remote desktop and configure the firewall accordingly.